# Discord Python API needs to be updated to the latest version (1.4.1) on Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

Posting here since I am only using free dynos for my discord bot and can't contact Heroku support directly so hope someone who can fix the issue sees this.

I have a discord bot written in python. The bot had been running for a long time without issue but has stopped since the latest update to the python discord API. Before someone says to version lock the bot in the previous API version where it worked, be aware that older versions of the python discord API cannot connect to the discord servers anymore due to internal changes in the base discord API that lead to the python discord API update so that wouldn't help.

When I run the bot on my local system it works as it used to since I have updated my python discord API version.

What I did for the update to fully work on my system (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in WSL) was to update the python discord API and then reinstall yarl as follows:

```
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py

mkdir ~/backup
mv ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl* ~/backup/
pip3 install yarl --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a file called `requirements.txt` inside that file place all your dependencies. It should build itself and adding all the required dependencies.

```
discord.py==1.4.1
```

Comment: This seems to have worked to force it to use the newest version, though tbh I shouldn't need a workaround to force use a version of a package when the old version is fully deprecated and doesn't work anymore.

Thank you for the reply :)